# Loop through a List<string> but only take a part of each string inside

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am wondering if anyone can help me, I am trying to loop through a list of strings but only take the part to the left of ":" but not including the ":" I can do this with the approach below but I am trying to implement this by using Linq instead. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
        List<string> Results = new List<string>();

        List<string> strings = new List<string>
        {
            "121:sdfdsfds",
            "122:sdfdsfds",
            "123:sdfdsfds"
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < strings.Count; i++)
        {
            string[] tokens = strings[i].Split(':');
            if (tokens.Any())
            {
                Results.Add(tokens[0]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried? From looking also you might not have a `:` in it - is that right?

Comment: Yes I don't want the " :" I tried things like strings.Select(c => c.Split(':').Take(1));

Comment: And that near enough works. The only issue is it returns an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` instead of `IEnumerable<string>`. IF you'd just used `First()` instead of `Take(1)` you'd have had it. And this is why you should always include what you've tried so we can explain why what you tried didn't work so you can learn more than just by somebody giving you the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.110).aspx) method (`System.Linq` namespace)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> strings = new List<string>
        {
            "121:sdfdsfds",
            "122:sdfdsfds",
            "123:sdfdsfds"
        };

        List<string> Results = strings
            .Select(s => s.Split(':')[0])
            .ToList();

        Results.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Output:

> 121
>   122
>   123

Answer (score 3):

Method chain syntax:

```
List<string> Results = strings.Select(t => t.Split(':'))
       .Where(tokens => tokens.Any())
       .Select(tokens => tokens[0]).ToList();
```

Query syntax:

```
List<string> Results = (from t in strings
    select t.Split(':')
    into tokens
    where tokens.Any()
    select tokens[0]).ToList();
```

Comment: The former is usually referred to as method syntax (cf https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Chris I wasn't 100% sure what the correct term is.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> Results = strings
    .Select(item => item.Split(':').FirstOrDefault())
    .Where(item => item != null).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take each item of the string array, split it, and return index[0] all inside a select statement:

```
var results = strings.Select(i => i.Split(':')[0]).ToList();
```

If there's a chance that some items will be empty and you don't want to include them, you can use this syntax on the string.Split method:

```
var results = strings
    .Select(i => i.Split(new[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .FirstOrDefault())
    .Where(i => i != null)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This won't work if you have empty entries. If one of the strings is `""` then your split will return an empty array and you will then attempt to access the first element of that array leading to an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: Try running this command: `Console.WriteLine("".Split(new[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length);` - it will print 0. While normally you are right you have told it to remove empty entries so if the string was empty then the split will return an array with one empty item that will then be removed leaving nothing in the array and thus your Exception.

Comment: Oh, you're right! I was only thinking about the first option...thanks! I will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Use forEach,
        `strings.ForEach(x => Results.Add(x.Split(':')[0]));`